# How to keep a specific type of element from being stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have code that has a user input numbers that are stored in an array. I would like to know how to prevent a user from entering a negative number in the array and showing in red (preferably red text below input) that they can't enter a negative number

I was able to get the array to identify what type of integer is put into an array with an if... else statement, but I can't seem to get the array to pop off the negative number.

```html
<input type="number" id="user_input">
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click to store</button>

<script>
  const myArray = [];

  const addData = () => {
    let inputData = document.getElementById('user_input');
    myArray.push(parseInt(inputData.value));
    console.log(myArray);

    if (inputData.value <= 0) {
      console.log("negative int")
    } else if (inputData.value == 0) {
      console.log('nothing entered')
    } else {
      console.log("positive int")
    }

    inputData.value = "";
  }
  document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', addData);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the numerical value and check if the string is given or if this value is an integer value, or negative. Then you need function for showing a wanted message with a certain color.

This solution features an [*exit early, exit often* paradigm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement), where the function takes a condition and exits if the condition is met, to prevent to go to the natural end of the function by using a chained `else ... if ... else` structure.

In short, this approach works without `else` parts, which is here possible.

```js
const
    myArray = [],
    addData = () => {
        const setMessage = (string, color = '#000000') => {
            message.style.color = color;
            message.innerHTML = string;
        }
 
        let inputData = document.getElementById('user_input'),
            message = document.getElementById('message'),
            value = +inputData.value;
  
        if (inputData.value === '') {
            setMessage('nothing entered', '#bb0000');
            return;
        }
        inputData.value = "";
        if (value !== Math.floor(value)) {
            setMessage('no int', '#bb0000');
            return;
        }
        if (value <= 0) {
            setMessage('negative int', '#bb0000');
            return;
        }
        myArray.push(value);
        console.log(myArray);
        setMessage('positive int');
}

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', addData);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="user_input">
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click to store</button>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're pushing the value in the array **before** checking for its type. You just have to do it like this to prevent negative numbers to get inside the array :

```
        const myArray = [];


        const addData = () => {
            let inputData = document.getElementById('user_input');
            console.log(myArray);

            if (inputData.value <= 0) {
                console.log("negative int")
            } else if (inputData.value == 0) {
                console.log('nothing entered')
            } else {
                console.log("positive int")
                myArray.push(parseInt(inputData.value));
            }

            inputData.value = ""; 
        }
        document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', addData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, very simply `<input type="number" id="user_input" min="0">`